# SOAP UI Summary Reports while running from Command line

Tags: soapui

While running SOAPUI test cases  from command line the summary report showing the details of entire testing. Is there a way to get Individual transaction time for each  test cases instead total time in summary report?

Thanks,
Sasi

Answer (score 2):

Summary report is for reporting test summary and not for reporting individual tests.A detailed report is automatically generate once you ran the test suit /test cases from command line with all the required information like status,time taken,size,request and response for each transaction.